# Can you use forms within PHP echo?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a form from within an echo statement in my PHP code, everything works except for the submit button, when I click it, it just takes me to the same page I'm in instead of purchase.php

It works when I copy the form out of PHP and use paste it in plain html but that doesn't serve what I need, why would the action of a form not work in a PHP echo?

I tried using escape characters for the quotations, starting a completely fresh echo statement, seperated it from the others, nothing worked, I keep getting redirected to the same page like it's an empty submit button

```
if($_POST['SELECTION'] == "sony"){

  
  $data=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products where prod_type = 'sony' ");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  echo"
  <div class='w3-quarter'>
      <img src='".$row['img_link']."' width='200px' height='300px' alt='iphone12' style='width:100%'>
      <h3>".$row['prod_name']."</h3>
      <p>".$row['prod_desc']."</p>
    <p>".$row['prod_price']."</p>
    <p>". "<form method='POST' action='purchase.php'> <div id = 'hidden' > <input type ='text' name='ninjaid' value='".$row['prod_id']."' > </div> <input type='submit' name='buy' value='Buy'> </form>"." </p> 
    
  
  ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> use single quote on the outside and double quotes inside   working
> fine

```
echo '
  <div class="w3-quarter">
      <img src="'.$row['img_link'].'" width="200px" height="300px" alt="iphone12" style="width:100%">
      <h3>"'.$row['prod_name'].'"</h3>
      <p>"'.$row['prod_desc'].'"</p>
    <p>"'.$row['prod_price'].'"</p>
    <p><form method="POST" action="purchase.php"> <div id = "hidden" > <input type ="text" name="ninjaid" value="'.$row['prod_id'].'" > </div> <input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy"> </form></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces  to enclose variables {$var} instead ."$var".  to avoid problems with arrays

```
    if($_POST['SELECTION'] == "sony"){

  
  $data=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products where prod_type = 'sony' ");

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  echo"
  <div class='w3-quarter'>
      <img src='{$row['img_link']}' width='200px' height='300px' alt='iphone12' style='width:100%'>
      <h3>{$row['prod_name']}</h3>
      <p>{$row['prod_desc']}</p>
    <p>{$row['prod_price']}</p>
    <p><form method='POST' action='purchase.php'> <div id = 'hidden' > <input type ='text' name='ninjaid' value='{$row['prod_id']}' > </div> <input type='submit' name='buy' value='Buy'> </form>"." </p> 
    
  
  ";
  }
```